# How can I reassemble a disassembled .dylib (Mac OS X) (.asm) that depends on QT?

Tags: xcode, macos, qt, assembly, disassembly

I disassembled a dylib file using hopper disassembler, this library depends on QT framework. I just changed a few instructions in assembly code and tried to use the option in hopper to "generate new executable". It created a copy of the source file without my changes. I assume that this was because this was a library and not an executable. I could save to an .asm file but now I don´t know how to reassemble the file again to make the library work as before. Do I need to program in XCode to do this?  Is there a tutorial in the web I can follow to do this?Can I do this with MonoDevelop?  Please let me know as I am toally clueless here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you operate on the library directly with a hex editor?

Comment: Strongly second this; if you're only changing a few instructions then directly editing the object (your shared lib) is much easier than trying to recompile reverse-engineered code, because the structure and contents of a shared lib depend a lot on _how_ (which compiler / linker switches and flags were used) it was compiled and linked. You cannot recover/reverse engineer this fully if all you have is the object; in-place editing removes the need to do so.

Comment: I have the executable and the dylib, I am trying to use hopper disassembler to understand the calls from the executable to the dylib. Yes I can use a hex editor but I only see hex. As you can see I don´t have a lot of experience disassembling. Is there a way to debug the dylib itself with breakpoints?  It is possible with the executable, I have done it.